# FragmentTabHost not showing tab content

Tags: android

I have a problem on displaying child fragment(fragment in fragment) with FragmentTabHost in my program. The tab host is displayed perfectly but its content does not been shown...

First, introduce the classes:

Order.java:

```
public class Order extends Fragment{
    private View view;
    private FragmentTabHost orderMenu;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order, container, false);
        setLayout();
        return view;
    }

    public void setLayout(){
        orderMenu = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.order_tabhost);
        orderMenu.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.order_tabcontent);

        Bundle testArg1 = new Bundle();
        testArg1.putString("tag", "t1");

        Bundle testArg2 = new Bundle();
        testArg2.putString("tag", "t2");

        Bundle testArg3 = new Bundle();
        testArg3.putString("tag", "t3");

        orderMenu.addTab(orderMenu.newTabSpec("t1").setIndicator("fruit"), OrderMenuList.class, testArg1);
        orderMenu.addTab(orderMenu.newTabSpec("t2").setIndicator("bird"), OrderMenuList.class, testArg2);
        orderMenu.addTab(orderMenu.newTabSpec("t3").setIndicator("meat"), OrderMenuList.class, testArg3);
    }   

}
```

order.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/order_tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/order_tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>


</LinearLayout>
```

OrderMenuList.java

```
public class OrderMenuList extends Fragment{
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    private View view;
    private ListView menuList;

    private String[] menu1 = {"apple", "orange", "banana", "melon"};
    private String[] menu2 = {"duck", "chicken", "turkey"};
    private String[] menu3 = {"steak", "pork"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, ""+this.getArguments().getString("tag"));
        setLayout();
        return view;
    }

    public void setLayout(){
        menuList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
        if (this.getArguments()!=null){
            if (this.getArguments().getString("tag").equals("t1")){
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu1);
            } else if (this.getArguments().getString("tag").equals("t2")){
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu2);
            } else if (this.getArguments().getString("tag").equals("t3")){
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu3);
            }
        }
        menuList.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(TAG, ""+adapter.getCount());
    }
}
```

menu_list.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have also tried simply put a textview instead of listview to test it but it also does not work. So, for now stage, my aim is very simple........show the tab content in the fragment!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `FrameLayout` with `android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"`, so it occupies all available height. But you setup your `FragmentTabHost` with `R.id.order_tabcontent` which resides below, so you don't see it.

Remove one of `FrameLayout`'s and setup `FragmentTabHost` with another.

Comment: I remove order_tabcontent and then it works, thanks:)
but need to notice it should also change R.id.order_tabcontent to android.R.id.tabcontent in setup()

Comment: @Simon you are welcome! I wrote exactly this: *setup FragmentTabHost with another*.